# Joining two tables but removing rows already present in another

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, duplicates

I have four tables:

days

```
CREATE TABLE days (
day text priamry key
);
```

These days run `monday` to `saturday`.

times

```
CREATE TABLE times (
time time Primary Key,
peak text 
);
```

The time run from 8:00 am to 9:00 pm in hour slots E.g. 8:00, 9:00, 10:00, 11:00

activities

```
CREATE TABLE activities (
activity text primary key
);
```

and planner

```
CREATE TABLE planner (
day text foriegn key references days (day)
time time foriegn key references times (time)
activity text foriegn key references activities (activity)
member bigint
primary key (day, time, member)
);
```

The planner table will have data like:

```
friday, 09:00, squash_court1 , 2
friday, 09:00, squash_court2 , 3
friday, 09:00, squash_court3 , 1
```

What I am wanting to do i make a list of all the none booked times for these three courts
So I would have a list like

```
time  activity
08:00 squash_court1
10:00 squash_court1
...rest of times...
08:00 squash_court2
10:00 squash_court2
...rest of times...
08:00 squash_court3
10:00 squash_court3
...rest of times...
```

an the reason these is no 9:00 between 8:00 and 10:00 is because it has been booked

EDIT

At the moment I have the basic join of:

```
SELECT time , activity FROM times, activities;
```

All I need now is the `WHERE` clause to remove the ones that are booked in the `planner` table.

Thank you for any advice on this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All I need now is the `WHERE` clause to remove the ones that are booked in the `planner` table.

This can be done in various ways. `LEFT JOIN / WHERE .. IS NULL` often produces the fastest plan in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT t.time, a.activity
FROM   (days d CROSS JOIN  times t CROSS JOIN activities a)
LEFT   JOIN planner p ON (p.day, p.time, p.activity)
                       = (d.day, t.time, a.activity)
WHERE  p.activity IS NULL;
```

I use parenthesis to make clear you want to `CROSS JOIN` (same as a comma between the tables) `days`and `times` and `activities` first. These parenthesis are redundant, because tables are joined from left to right by default.

The `JOIN` condition is just a shorter form of:

```
 ON p.day = d.day
AND p.time = t.time
AND p.activity = a.activity
```

---

Another way would be a `NOT EXISTS` semi-join:

```
SELECT t.time, a.activity
FROM   (days d CROSS JOIN  times t CROSS JOIN activities a)
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM   planner 
   WHERE (p.day, p.time, p.activity)
       = (d.day, t.time, a.activity)
   );
```

Comment: that works great thanks, where could a put a day into that.
as it may be friday that some things are booked and saturday different things are booked and id like to see the wto different table for the fridya and satruday.

Comment: @DannyCalladine: I added in the missing days.

Comment: ok that give me for every day that is in the day table what if i wanted to choose a specific day for it to show me. so i want to see fridays part of the table that the above statement cretes

Comment: and also if i wanted to choose a specific activity

Comment: @DannyCalladine: Add to the `WHERE` clause for that. Like: `AND d.day = 'Friday'. Same goes for activities. Very basic, really.

Comment: Thank you. i was putting the extra where clauses in the wrong bit of the brackets that why i couldn't get it to work Thank you though